# Cannot access memory as SSE type on x86 but works fine on x64

Tags: c++, x86, sse

I've got some code written using the MSVC SSE intrinsics.

```
            __m128 zero = _mm_setzero_ps();
            __m128 center = _mm_load_ps(&sphere.origin.x);
            __m128 boxmin = _mm_load_ps(&rhs.BottomLeftClosest.x);
            __m128 boxmax = _mm_load_ps(&rhs.TopRightFurthest.x);

            __m128 e = _mm_add_ps(_mm_max_ps(_mm_sub_ps(boxmin, center), zero), _mm_max_ps(_mm_sub_ps(center, boxmax), zero));
            e = _mm_mul_ps(e, e);

            __declspec(align(16)) float arr[4];
            _mm_store_ps(arr, e);
            float r = sphere.radius;
            return (arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] <= r * r);
```

The `Math::Vector` type (which is the type of `sphere.origin`, `rhs.BottomLeftClosest`, and `rhs.TopRightFurthest`) is effectively an array of 3 floats. I aligned them to 16 bytes and this code executes fine on x64. But on x86 I get access violation reading a null pointer. Any advice on where this comes from?

Comment: Misaligned SSE access will show up as a null pointer access.

Comment: @Mysticial: But I aligned them to 16bytes.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like misaligned loads. Try using `loadu` instead of `load`, just to see if the error goes away. Or just step through in the debugger, and examine the addresses

Comment: Ok, what's going on with the downvotes?

Comment: Debug menu -> Windows -> Disassembly (or just ALT+8 while in debugger).

Comment: I'll also warn you that storing data with one register size and immediately loading the same data with a different register size will often lead to a 10-20+ cycle stall.

Comment: This is most likely an unaligned access. Possibly the maximum stack alignment for x86 windows is 8 bytes? @jalf Somebody seems to randomly downvote everything containing SSE.

Comment: @drhirsch "Somebody seems to randomly downvote everything containing SSE." - Micro-optimziation questions are quite prone to that. Apparently some believe that micro-optimization is inherently premature and evil.

Comment: @jalf Questions like "why does <random piece of code with no context> crash" deserve to be downvoted. The only valid answer for such questions is "your debugger will tell you". [Also, I've run into some weird codegen stuff with MSVC+SSE: I don't exclude a compiler bug.]

Comment: @zvrba: so you're saying a question where the answer might be a compiler bug *should be closed*? I think if "compiler bug" is a potential answer, that implies that the question has enough value to be asked and answered. Besides, the question is not "why does this code crash with no context". There is quite a bit of context: it's SSE code, and SSE is alignment-sensitive. It works on x64, which implies that the answer is more interesting than a simple logic bug. There is enough context for the question to be answered.

Comment: @jalf The question, which is *only* answerable by a debugger (as in this case -- the code is apparently correct; simple inspection in a debugger would reveal misalignment; but this also includes compiler bugs) should be closed as too localized, yes. Plus, there is no evidence in the question that assumptions (about arguments been properly aligned) have been verified. Definitely downvote or close.

Comment: @zvrba: if you need evidence that assumptions have been verified, then you can close 98.8% of all questions on SO. Given that an answer has been written and accepted, I think you'll find it hard to argue that the question cannot be answered. This question is worthwhile in that the answer is non-obvious. Normally, if your code generates an access violation reading a null pointer, you look for null pointers being dereferenced. You, I and the OP know that. But here, there were no null pointers, and the compiler gave no clue that alignment was the problem.

Comment: So if you don't happen to know that misaligned loads manifest themselves as access violations (which isn't exactly obvious), then you can debug it as much as you like, and the code just won't... make... sense. I think that's a good reason to post a question on SO

Comment: @jalf Except it wasn't acces violation due to null pointer exception, *and* he knew that variables had to be 16-byte aligned as witnessed by the question. With a bit of debugging he would have been able to *deduce* what happens on unaligned loads, even if he originally *didn't* know (aha! that's what happens when I don't do what CPU demands). And the question is incomplete because relevant information (declarations of variables involved) is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        __m128 center = _mm_load_ps(&sphere.origin.x);
```

_mm_load_ps() requires that the passed pointer is 16-byte aligned.  There's no evidence that you ensured that sphere.origin.x is aligned properly.  You'll need to use _mm_loadu_ps() instead if you can't provide that guarantee.

Comment: This certainly solved the problem. Apparently, adding `__declspec(align(16))` to the declaration of `origin` did not, actually, mean that it was 16byte aligned. Oh well. Thanks for this.

Comment: Right, doesn't work, you cannot align structure or class members.

Comment: It would be nice if the compiler had mentioned that.

Comment: Well, that's difficult because it cannot guess that you require absolute alignment instead of relative alignment.  You can post feature requests to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: So how can one access large arrays of floats? You can assure the first element is 16 Byte element, what about the others?